# Server side rendering react - Virtual DOM?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I recently started looking into SSR(Server side rendering) and I am impressed with its advantages. To name a few Load times, SEO, No javascript configuration.

However I am trying to understand if react server side rendering is worth it.
React is known for its Virtual DOM manipulations but using react with server side rendering will not give benefits of reactJs.

Can some one shed your ideas on using reactJS for server side rendering?

Comment: But i didnt find a proper answer for this. I am not seeing much use of using reactJS for server side rendering. Was not sure if this is invalid question. It would be helpful if I am directed to the right direction.

Comment: Server-side React will, ultimately, simply output a string of HTML for the client, just as if it was rendered by a PHP framework or ASP.NET Razor. So in the end, you can even use it for a 100% server-side rendered web-application, without React on the frontend.

Comment: React is still a nice way to generate html in node.js servers, even if the resulting HTML is static and just returned to the clients.

Comment: So from above comments,  i can see no Virtual DOM advantage rather than that, all html generation will be done at server side and returned to client where html will be rendered directly

Answer (score 4):

Using server-side rendering in React does **not imply** that React will not be used on client-side.

One of completely valid approaches is to start with client-side rendering only. In this case you have to setup a single HTML element in your HTML file that will become a hook for React once it loads.

Just to give you an example, let's say we have an `<div id="root"></div>` element in `index.html` file that will be served if we HTTP GET `/` path on our server. Initial document (in our case `index.html`) should also reference javascript file that includes React and our code. It can be done by adding something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/index.js"></script>` just before `</body>` tag.

At some point while `index.js` is executed, `ReactDOM.render()` method is called (note: we are in the browser right now) - this is a moment in time when React looks for a div element with `root` id attached in a document. After it's found, it becomes `react-root` - component tree is mounted under this element and managed by React (ie. virtual DOM, event handlers, state updates).

Please note that this approach requires that at least one javascript file is fetched, parsed and executed before browser can render **anything** meaningful (other than an empty div) to a user. For some scenarios, this is not acceptable and this is where SSR (server-side rendering) can help.

Server-side rendering requires that you have JavaScript runtime environment available on your server. One of the popular choices is Node.js (others include for example Nashron for JVM).

In approach, you execute React on the server and use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` (or `ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream()`) method to generate HTML response that is sent to the client - instead of an almost empty response with just one placeholder div as previously, now you can send all the markup that will be generated from your component tree (important note here is that in React 16.4(+) only `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` lifecycle method is called on server-side). After the initial response with a document is sent to the client, browser can render the initial markup before `index.js` even finishes downloading. Once it does, `ReactDOM.hydrate()` method kicks in. Hydration is a process of using existing server-side rendered markup and "watering" it with javascript goodies like event handlers. After it's done, this component tree is now completely managed by React with all the benefits.

Please note that in SSR, exactly the same component tree is rendered on a server-side and that's then hydrated on a client-side.

Of course, React can also be used instead of templating engines as a very powerful static HTML markup generator. All you need to do is to render the markup on the server with `ReactDOMServer. renderToStaticMarkup()` and send it to the client. It should be noted that this approach has a significant performance impact (https://malloc.fi/performance-cost-of-server-side-rendered-react-node-js) and uses a very limited number of React features.

Comment: ok. So whenever a route changes, only then content will be prepared at Server side as part of Server side rendering and  returned to client and from then Virtual DOM comes into picture.

Comment: No, Virtual DOM will not be used in this case as server does not (normally) keep client's component tree - it's stateless in this regard. Whenever the route changes, server will generate a new component tree and send the new response - meaning full page reload. What can be done though is that initial document is send from the server and then any subsequent route changes are client-side (just like in SPA).

Comment: @catchergeese can you comment on the scalability of ReactJS SSR on a high scale. If there are large number of page hits on a logged in pages with dynamic content, do you recommend migrating out of Nunjucks to ReactJS SSR. We are looking to refactor to ReactJS SPA for an existing MPA solution. Its the SSR bit on scale which concerns me. Do you have any experience to share ?

Comment: Thank you for your question, @sudhanshu. It's really relevant one although it's hard to provide silver-bullet answer as use cases differ significantly and "High scale" is rather relative term but let me share my experience on more general level. There is a non-negligible additional effort pressure on your server when SSRing - good starting point can be to have a look at https://malloc.fi/performance-cost-of-server-side-rendered-react-node-js.

Comment: Yes I have gone through this as long as it meets those throughputs I am good. Other issue I was pondering is selling something like NextJS at multiple projects in my company. It will bring lots of opinionated style of NextJS onto ReactJS. Like React Router has to be turned down.